# Can you override ag-grids balham themes cursor dynamically?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to dynamically change the css-property cursor to "wait" while the application does an api call. I've added

```
document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
```

prior to the ajax, but it does not take effect over my ag-grid. My guess is that the ag-grid-balham class overrides the cursor property. How can I force my override to trump balhams?

Answer (score 1):

you can. By using a custom class its easy to override styles for AG GRID.

```
create a class like this 
.custom-wait-class .ag-root-wrapper,
.custom-wait-class .ag-side-button-button{
cursor : wait !important;
}
```

and then add/remove this class while doing data load.

```
 var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
eGridDiv.classList.add('custom-wait-class');
  // create the grid passing in the div to use together with the columns & data we want to use
  new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);

  agGrid.simpleHttpRequest({url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/src/sample-data/rowData.json'}).then(function(data) {
      gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);


//remove class here 
eGridDiv.classList.remove('custom-wait-class')
  });
```

here is [demo plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/bIlxrM7cUIkNpGrd)